# Typescript works with inline on map but not with interface

Tags: typescript, dictionary, interface, inline

I'm gradually adding Typescript to an Nextjs app but I've hit an issue. In the map function Typescript works as expected if I write the type checks inline but not if I use an interface. Can anyone help me understand why this is the case? It seems to be specific to the map function.

(image: { id: number; label: string; url: string }) - catches type errors

(image: Image) - doesn't catch types errors

Here's the code:

```
import Slider from 'react-slick';
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick.css';
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css';

interface Image {
    id: number;
    url: string;
    label: string;
}

interface Project {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    images: Image[];
}

interface Props {
    project: Project;
}

const Carousel = ({ project }: Props) => {
    const settings = {
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 500,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: false,
    };

    const getSlider = () => {
        if (project !== undefined) {
            return (
                <Slider {...settings}>
                    {project.images.map(
                        // (image: Image) => (
                        (image: { id: number; label: string; url: string }) => (
                            <div className='slider-slide' key={image.id}>
                                <img
                                    className='slick-slide-image'
                                    src={image.url}
                                    width='100%'
                                    height='auto'
                                />
                                <label className='slick-slide-label mt-2'>
                                    {image.label}
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        )
                    )}
                </Slider>
            );
        } else return null;
    };

    return getSlider();
};

export default Carousel;
```

Update:

I've discovered that if I just use a simple array such as...

```
const images = [{
    id: 1,
    url: 'dave.jpg',
    label: 'dave',
},
{
      id: 2,
      url: 'doug.jpg',
    label: 'doug',
}]
```

...and change the map to...

```
{images.map((image: Image) => console.log('label', image.label)}
```

...type checking works fine.
So can someone sanity check the way I've set up the interfaces as they look correct to me?

Comment: Both had worked for me when I tried on the TS playground. Can you try changing the name of your `Image` interface to something weird like `Image22`? Just want to verify that there's not a global conflict with some other interface called `Image`.

Comment: That's a good shout but unfortunately it didn't affect the outcome.